# Extract main directory name of php application

Tags: php, directory, separator

> I would like to get only the application name of my project, For
> example my application name(Directory Name) is : **MERP** The path of
> the application is: C:/xampp/htdocs/**MERP**
> So I need to get only the name
> **MERP**.
>
> There is another way storing application name inside a config file using define syntax and
> include in all the files, but my scenario is stuck with this step
> only.

Comment: basename?  Something like `basename(__DIR__)`, but depends on your project structure.   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: You could use an environment variable if you are allergic to includes.

Comment: `basename(__DIR__)` should return only the directory name of the file that it is called in without the full path.  So if you called that within /path/to/htdocs/MERP/foo.php, it should return MERP.

Comment: yes here is the issue is that i need to access the application from different levels of directories (sub directories & sub-sub directories) .

Comment: Within and under the MERP directory?

Comment: yes my application have different directories,
`MERP/module_hr/`
`MERP/module_hr/reports `
and so on..

Comment: What have yout ried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Php files under a directory within and under your document root:

You could try:

```
strtok(str_replace(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), '', __FILE__), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

However, this is still brittle.  And I would advice against it, preferring a setup/bootstrap file with constant declaration, and a possible place for common functions.

Php allows for a common file to be applied before your scripts, see the [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.  This might be useful if you want to go beyond a few constants, and saves the require lines from individual files.

If you only wish for a handful of constants, consider environmental variables.

Comment: result is empty.

Comment: @Moussa well that's embarassing, I've fixed the argument order.

Comment: it is showing the full url path . what i need is only to extract the main application directory name that comes after the htdocs ...

Comment: @Moussa how are you running that?  Through the command line or through XAMPP?

Comment: running through xampp

Comment: now only showing result`C:`  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is working normally showing the path

Comment: @Moussa Will request the full output of this again please: `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], __FILE__);`, you didn't last time.

Comment: From Local : `string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" string(48) "C:\xampp\htdocs\MERP\MERP\module_hr\addbonus.php" ` from web server external `string(20) "C:/xampp/htdocs/MERP" string(48) "C:\xampp\htdocs\MERP\MERP\module_hr\addbonus.php" `

Comment: Aha, will need to canonicalise the slashes.

Comment: @Moussa I did that, added realpath.

Comment: when i open the application from an external web server which is linking to folder MERP2 , it is showing me index.php instead of MERP2

Comment: @Moussa what do you mean by is linking to folder MERP2?  Perhaps your document root is the same as MERP2?  I suggested this was a brittle approach.  You'd be better using a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can use this to get the MERP dictionary name just this php codes below

```
basename(__DIR__);
```

If You want to get and output you can use an `echo` before that code

If you have multiple dictionaries in the parent please use this code:

```
<?php


$rootAfter = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dir_array = parse_url($rootAfter);
preg_match('@/(?<path>[^/]+)@', $dir_array['path'], $x);
$folderName = $x['path'];
echo $folderName;


?>
```

More details are on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: I can't use this code because I'm accessing files from different directory levels , like `MERP/module_hr/reports` and another level like `MERP/module_sales/reports/admin`

Comment: Hello can you please specify that are you using a web server or local host

Comment: I'm using both .

Comment: works great !!! but wondering if there is shorter code because this code will run on each page of the application . Thank You

Comment: You can make a function out of it

Comment: when i open the application from an external web server which is linking to folder MERP2 , it is showing me index.php instead of MERP2

Comment: It may be you have use .htaccess rules in the server to rewrite the path

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of job I usually use [getcvd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) , having, for example, apache vhost pointing on public/index, it will return full/path/to/merp/public .
From this value you can go up using [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

If you are not using the "public" dir, getcvd will be enough.